# Video url play on ipad browser but not in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to display the on demand video from the server. I am using the `MPMoviePlayerController` for this. Its working fine for the some of the streaming URL provided by the apple.
For Example : http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

Video URL provided by my client is not working in the same code. I am getting `-1001 error` which in the request time out but the same URL working fine on the iPad browser.

How can I debug this issue ? How can I identify the probable cause of this request time out.

I am aware about the `mediastreamvalidator` tool but I have no idea weather my client has implemented HTTP streaming on the server side or not.

Kindly guid me to debug it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which video format your client is using???

Comment: Sharon, we are using .mp4 format.

Comment: That should work fine for streaming .. a look into the code will help all of us to understand what's wrong.

Comment: will you please post some code, we can't help with a guess!

Comment: Dpk, I have referred the example source code provided by the apple. link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html Even same video URL is not working in that source code too.

Comment: MP4 can not be streamed but only progressively downloaded. Do not use MP4 video but M3U8 HTTP-streaming.